# Identifying the assembly of a composable part

Tags: mef

Suppose I define an export in AssemblyA:

```
[Export(typeof(Foo))]
public class Foo
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to determine the export of Foo is from AssemblyA in the CompositionContainer?

What I am trying to do, is for any given assembly that provides MEF exports, it must also include one MEF export of a specific interface. And I want to be able to flag any assemblies that do not satisfy this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this from in a CompositionContainer.  I would suggest creating an AssemblyCatalog for each assembly and checking whether any of its Parts have an ExportDefinition matching the interface you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the type and assembly of a [ComposablePartDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepartdefinition.aspx) using the static [ReflectionModelServices.GetPartType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.reflectionmodel.reflectionmodelservices.getparttype.aspx) method. The following example creates a list of distinct assemblies that contain types included in the container's catalog:

```
var assemblies = container.Catalog.Parts
    .Select(part => ReflectionModelServices.GetPartType(part).Value.Assembly)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```